# prove that $[(n-1)!/n]$ is even for n>4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

'[]' refers to the greatest integer function.
I have tried expanding the factorial and applying greatest integer function properties but could not prove it.

Comment: @J.vanderHooft With indutcion ? How can we deal with the floor-function this way ?

Comment: For a prime $n$ , Wilson's theorem says that $(n-1)!+1$ is didivible by $n$ and for $n>4$, the quotient is obviously odd. Since the desired number is $1$ less, for primes the claim follows. For composite $n>4$, $\frac{(n-1)!}{n}$ is an integer and using Betrand's postulate, it should be possible to show that it is even.

Comment: @Peter That's not Bertrand's postilate, it's just counting the number of factors $2$ in $(n-1)!$ and in $n$ and see that the former has more.

Comment: @Arthur If you have an easier proof of that (not using Bertrand's postulate), post it. I will upvote it.

Comment: **Stop asking or answering PSQs**.PSQ stands for Problem Solving Questions that specifically refer to that type of questions which ask you for an answer for a question without showing any efforts or working. This has been a matter of great discussion in Meta recently. We do not want to ruin our site into a homework solving place. Thanks!

Comment: I'm really regretting asking the question here.All I have been getting are negative responses.I believe these are the people who have no clue about the problem but want to show that they are intellectually superior or want to increase their repo or what not.There have been only a few answers that too were unable to clearly explain the concept .I hope you all fail your math exams like I 'm about to .

Comment: The bigshots who don't know the answer vote to close the question. We have seen that plenty of times.

Answer (score 2):

@Peter above proves it for $n$ being prime, and points out that if $n$ is composite and greater than $4$, then $\frac{(n-1)!}n$ is an integer, so we can disregard the greatest integer brackets. It remains to show that this integer is even.

I will do this by counting the number of factors $2$ in $(n-1)!$ and in $n$, and see that there are too many of them in $(n-1)!$ to be cancelled out by $n$ (as long as $n>4$).

Each even number less than or equal to $n-1$ contributes at least one factor $2$ to $(n-1)!$. There are $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor$ of those. Each factor of $4$ contributes at least one more. There are $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}4\right\rfloor$ of those. In total, that means that if we write $(n-1)!$ as $2^k \cdot m$ where $m$ is odd, then $k> \frac{3n}4 - 2$, which in turn implies that $2^k > n$. We can do the same to $n$, getting $n = 2^r\cdot p$ with $p$ odd, and $2^r\leq n$. We now have
$$
\frac{(n-1)!}{n} = \frac{2^k\cdot m}{2^r\cdot p} \\
= \frac{2^k}{2^r}\cdot\frac{m}{p}
$$
Both the fractions on the last line must be integers, and especially since $2^k> n\geq 2^r$, the left fraction must be an even integer, and we're done.

Comment: I upvoted, but I will have to go through the details.

Comment: @Peter It's a bit iffy with the estimations for small $n$ (say between $5$ and $8$), which makes the answer seem a bit cumbersome. The idea is that for $(n-1)!$ to acquire another factor $2$, all you need to do is increase $n$ by $2$, while for $n$ to acquire another factor $2$, you need to double it. Also, as you increase $n$ by $1$, the numerator doesn't lose its factors $2$ the way the denominator can.